# Alias substitution for a string to use it in a terminal command

Tags: bash, alias

Is there a way to substitute aliases such that it is appended or prepended to an existing command in the shell?

For example, defining the alias:

```
alias execloc='/home/user/'
```

Prepending this to a command in the bash terminal:

```
cd exeloc/temp/somefolder
```

Can something like this be done, or is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do it like this because `/home/user/` is not a command. It't more like a static string.

From `man bash` (somewhere at line 1984):

> Aliases  allow a string to be substituted for a word when it is used as
>       **the first word of a simple command**.

In your case, `execloc` will never be the first word of a simple command.

But, instead to define `execloc` as an alias, you can define it as an environment variable:

```
export execloc='/home/user/'
```

And then you can use it everywhere you want as follow:

```
cd $exeloc/temp/somefolder
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't *think* so with bash/dash, but I could be wrong. I think it may be possible with 'zsh' (alias -g foo='bar').

But there are some other possibilities.

If you are just wanting more convenient 'cd' commands, you could use CDPATH (google it).
Or use symlinks or hardlinks (man ln).

Or modify/create ~/.inputrc with a line like:

Control-f: "grep -r -i    .\e[D\e[D\e[D"

This types out a grep command for me and then backspaces to before the dot so I can type ctrl-f and then a word I'm searching for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it (if I read your question properly) as follows:

> export EXECLOG=/home/user
>
> cd $EXECLOG/temp/somefolder

Basically set up your substitutions in the shell and access them by prefixing them with the "$" sign. Standard shell variables.

(exited to fix typo in EXECLOG)

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/364851/147044)?

Comment: Yes, I have - have you tried to run what I suggested?  The substitution is done in the shell and will perform the example the OP posted.

Comment: Ah, now I see - your post contains what I posted as well - so I duplicated your answer.  SO although I did see your response, I didn't read it all the way through.  Take off the downvote and I'll remove the response.